# How to get `hasContent` without fetching the whole `content` using PrismaORM

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm using PrismaORM to hold a table containing Articles.

```
model Article {
  id           String     @default(cuid()) @id
  title        String     @default("")
  content      String?
}
```

Then I'm fetching these articles, and I'm sending the list to the front end. I don't want to send `content` though, since it could be very big, I just want to tell the frontend if the article is or not empty. I only want to send `{ id: string, title: string, hasContent: boolean }`.

Essentially, this:

```js
  const filters = { ... }

  const data = await prismaClient.entry.findMany({
    where: filters,
    select: {
      id: true,
      title: true,
      content: true,
    }
  })

  return data.map(entry => {
    return {
      ...omit(entry, ["content"]),
      hasContent: !!entry.content,
    }
  })
```

Problem is, for every article I'm fetching `content` from the DB, just to check if it's empty or not.

I'd rather do something like this:

```js
  const data = await prismaClient.entry.findMany({
    where: filters,
    select: {
      id: true,
      title: true,
      hasContent: {
        isEmpty: { content: true }
      },
    }
  })
```

Isn't there any way to do this?

To clarify, using SQL I'd do something like this:

```sql
SELECT ID, title, (CASE WHEN content = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_content
FROM Articles ;
```

Comment: Would adding a condition of content not equals to empty string ("") would work for you?

Comment: @NurulSundarani I don't think so, because I want all the entries, including the ones without content.